# Trigger to decrease a counter

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a trigger to decrease the quantity of available items after an order has been made.

I tried to create a trigger. I'm using phpMyAdmin, setting trigger `AFTER INSERT` in the table `products_in_order`

```
       SET @qtt = (
           SELECT quantity  
           FROM products_in_order
           ORDER BY inorder_id DESC
           LIMIT 1)

       SET @code = (
           SELECT product_code  
           FROM products_in_order
           ORDER BY inorder_id DESC
           LIMIT 1)

           UPDATE products 
           SET quantity = quantity-@qtt
           WHERE product_code=@code
```

Why does the first `SET` work, and the second, too, but as soon as I write them both, i get an error?

How to make this trigger work correctly?

Sample data:

`products` represents all products available in the shop, and has columns:

```
product_code | name | price | quantity
```

`product_in_order` represents a set of products of the same type, that can be added to order. It has colums:

<s>inorder_id | product_code | price | order_no</s>

```
inorder_id | product_code | price | quantity | order_no
```

When somebody adds a set of products to the order, I want the overall quantity of that product to decrease.

Comment: Thats unclear from the description. Provide some sample data from both tables and expected result by trigger. There are better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join back to the newly inserted / updated table* - just use the [`New` pseudo row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) from within your trigger, which already has the values you need to join into the master `Product` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `MyTrigger` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `products_in_order`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE products
           SET quantity = quantity-New.quantity
           WHERE product_code=New.product_code;
    END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6afd56/1) demonstrating that the starting value of `Product` is depleted by the amount inserted into `products_in_order` for the applicable product code.

`*` Assuming `inorder_id` is an AUTO_INCREMENT, selecting from this table twice without any locking considerations will also be prone to concurrency issues, e.g. if another writer inserts another row while your trigger is executing. Another good reason to use `New`

Comment: Yes, `inorder_id` is an AUTO_INCREMENT. I understand now, why it's bad to to select twice from the table. However, I still get a syntax error using this code.
EDIT: that was a typo. Thank you, it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was mistaken. I have an error when I try to `INSERT` something into the `products_in_order` table. This is the error #1054: "unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list'. How to fix it? It's not a spelling error in the `quantity` word, i double-checked.

Comment: From your table definitions, there is no `quantity` field on `products_in_order ` although your first query selects it (`SET @qtt ..`). Possibly you need to join to orders via `order_no` to get the quantity?

Comment: I forgot to add it, my bad, it's pretty essential. There is a `quantity` field on `products_in_order`.